# Return a specific part of a PHP Variable

Tags: php

Below is the return of `echo $product`

How can I get the value of `tickex_gamedate` i.e `20\/06\/2024` (but in a nice format)?

```
{
    "id":28,
    "name":"Serbia vs England",
    "slug":"serbia-vs-england",
    "date_created":
    {
        "date":"2024-01-23 14:30:32.000000",
        "timezone_type":3,
        "timezone":"Europe\/London"
    },
    "date_modified":
    {
        "date":"2024-01-23 16:44:32.000000",
        "timezone_type":3,
        "timezone":"Europe\/London"
    },
    "status":"publish",
    "featured":true,
    "catalog_visibility":"visible",
    "description":"",
    "short_description":"",
    "sku":"SERB_ENG",
    "price":"20",
    "regular_price":"20",
    "sale_price":"",
    "date_on_sale_from":null,
    "date_on_sale_to":null,
    "total_sales":0,
    "tax_status":"taxable",
    "tax_class":"",
    "manage_stock":false,
    "stock_quantity":null,
    "stock_status":"instock",
    "backorders":"no",
    "low_stock_amount":"",
    "sold_individually":false,
    "weight":"",
    "length":"",
    "width":"",
    "height":"",
    "upsell_ids":[],
    "cross_sell_ids":[],
    "parent_id":0,
    "reviews_allowed":false,
    "purchase_note":"",
    "attributes":[],
    "default_attributes":[],
    "menu_order":0,
    "post_password":"",
    "virtual":false,
    "downloadable":false,
    "category_ids":[15],
    "tag_ids":[],
    "shipping_class_id":0,
    "downloads":[],
    "image_id":"",
    "gallery_image_ids":[],
    "download_limit":-1,
    "download_expiry":-1,
    "rating_counts":[],
    "average_rating":"0",
    "review_count":0,
    "meta_data":
    [
        {
            "id":129,
            "key":"saso_eventtickets_list",
            "value":"1"
        },
        {
            "id":130,
            "key":"saso_eventtickets_is_ticket",
            "value":"yes"
        },
        {
            "id":131,
            "key":"saso_eventtickets_ticket_start_date",
            "value":"2024-06-16"
        },
        {
            "id":132,
            "key":"saso_eventtickets_ticket_max_redeem_amount",
            "value":"1"
        },
        {
            "id":133,
            "key":"saso_eventtickets_ticket_amount_per_item",
            "value":"1"
        },
        {
            "id":134,
            "key":"saso_eventtickets_list_formatter_values",
            "value":" {
                \"input_prefix_codes\":\"\",
                \"input_type_codes\":\"1\",
                \"input_amount_letters\":12,
                \"input_letter_excl\":\"2\",
                \"input_letter_style\":1,
                \"input_include_numbers\":\"1\",
                \"input_serial_delimiter\":\"1\",
                \"input_serial_delimiter_space\":null,
                \"input_number_start\":10000,
                \"input_number_offset\":1
            }"
        },
        {
            "id":180,
            "key":"tickex_gamedate",
            "value":"20\/06\/2024"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_json.asp

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like

```
foreach ($product->meta_data as $meta_data) {
    if ($meta_data->key === 'tickex_gamedate') {
        echo date('M d, Y', strtotime($meta_data->value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, unfortunately ```$meta_data``` doesn't return anything.

Comment: "Something like" this. It will depend on the details of your data types, which are not evident from the data you've shown. It looks like an object with properties, of which `meta_data` is an array of objects. If that's not the case, then the specifics of the extraction will vary a bit.